# How to dynamically generate C types?

Tags: c, macros, structure

I have to write a function `update(char* name, void* data);` which receives the name of the message and void* to the data of that message. The type of the data is always fixed as "xxx_name", depending on what the name is.

My function should do the following :-

1. Generate a new structure of type of xxx_name within the function.
2. Copy the data from the pointer data, of size xxx_name to a new location, as data would soon be freed by external interface.

In my case, the list of possible structures of type xxx_name is pretty huge and spread across, so writing if/else or switch conditions is out of question.

Is there a way to do this in C via some macro / stringizing operator etc?

Comment: Hashtable of names to functions.

Comment: You could do it if `name` were a constant string using a macro. The preprocessor runs before the compiler itself, so macros can never stringize or test the dynamic values of any variables.

Comment: When you say dynamically, that means at runtime? Or compile time? I'm thinking the former, and if so you're out of luck: that's not how C works.

Comment: If you're not required to use C, consider that many other languages have facilities that simplify such as task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses NULL terminated look up table (LUT) to find the appropriate size. Then allocates memory in that size. Then copies the input data to the new object. If the number of types of objects is large enough the LUT can be presorted then a binary search performed instead of a linear search.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct nameToSize_s {
    const char *name;
    size_t size;
};

struct foo1_name_s {
};

struct foo2_name_s {
};

const struct nameToSize_s nameToSizeLUT[] = {
    { "foo1_name",  sizeof(struct foo1_name_s) },
    { "foo2_name",  sizeof(struct foo2_name_s) },
    // NULL terminator
    { NULL, 0}
};

void * update(char* name, void *data) {
    const struct nameToSize_s *entry = nameToSizeLUT;

    while(entry->name) {
        if( strcmp(entry->name, name) == 0) break;
        entry++;
    }

    if( entry->name == NULL) abort();

    void *newObj = malloc(entry->size);
    if( newObj == NULL) abort();

    return memcpy( newObj, data, entry->size);
}
```

Comment: I agree, but i still have to type in all the foo1_name etc. ??

Comment: or write a script to generate the table. Somebody has to build the table.

Comment: I wrote script, Now i get this  
fatal error C1026: parser stack overflow, program too complex.
I am using VC++ 98 
I wrote it via simple if conditions :-
There are close to 5000 if conditions now

Comment: No idea why you would have any conditionals in your script. Do you have an example of the formats the types are in that you could add to the problem description? That would help with people's solutions.

Comment: If there are 5,000 named structs here, the list should be sorted by name so you can use a binary search. Linearly searching through 5,000 strings is just ... mean, at least if this happens at all often.